# Часы стоят на месте, а при обновлении странички время показывает нормально

Tags: php

Часы работают корректно время показывает как надо, Только они стоят на месте и секунды не тикают, при обновлении странички часы обновляются как надо, и время показывает нормально. Вопрос как запустить часы, чтобы они тикать начали? и секунды пошли в реальном времени когда находишся на сайте, часы уже связаны с зоной тайминговой - в этом проблем нет. Помогите пож запустить часы чтобы они пошли (секунда задвигались). Спасибо вам большое.
вот код

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function clock() {
    var d = new Date(<?=date("Y");?>, <?=(date("m")-1);?>, <?=date("d");?>, <?=date("H");?>, <?=date("i");?>, <?=date("s");?>);
    var month_num = d.getMonth()
    var day = d.getDate();
    var hours = d.getHours();
    var minutes = d.getMinutes();
    var seconds = d.getSeconds();

    month=new Array("января", "февраля", "марта", "апреля", "мая", "июня",
        "июля", "августа", "сентября", "октября", "ноября", "декабря");

    if (day <= 9) day = "0" + day;
    if (hours <= 9) hours = "0" + hours;
    if (minutes <= 9) minutes = "0" + minutes;
    if (seconds <= 9) seconds = "0" + seconds;

    date_time = "Екатеринбург - " + day + " " + month[month_num] + " " + d.getFullYear() +
        " г.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"+ hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    if (document.layers) {
        document.layers.doc_time.document.write(date_time);
        document.layers.doc_time.document.close();
    } else {
        document.getElementById("doc_time").innerHTML = date_time;
    }
    setTimeout("clock()", 1000);
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    clock();
</script>
```

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, в функцию setTimeOut передается только название функции без скобок. Уберите их, должно заработать: `setTimeout("clock", 1000);`

Answer (score 1):

```
if (document.layers) {
```

это с книги 97-99 года? Свойство [layers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mozilla_Web_Developer_FAQ#JavaScript_doesn.E2.80.99t_work.21_Why.3F) уже много лет  как не поддерживатся всеми доступными браузерами и является Netscape специфичным (да, был такой браузер).

Код я чуточку поправил, вместо

```
if (document.layers) {
document.layers.doc_time.document.write(date_time);
document.layers.doc_time.document.close();
}
else document.getElementById("doc_time").innerHTML = date_time;
setTimeout("clock()", 1000);
}
```

надо написать так

```
document.getElementById("doc_time").innerHTML = date_time;
setTimeout(clock, 1000);
```

И не забыть проверить, что есть тег `id="doc_time"`

Comment: прописываю так if (document.layers) {
 document.layers.doc_time.document.write(date_time);
 document.layers.doc_time.document.close();
}
document.getElementById("doc_time").innerHTML = date_time;
setTimeout(clock, 1000);
}

Comment: когда убираю if (document.layers) {
document.layers.doc_time.document.write(date_time);
document.layers.doc_time.document.close();
} часы перестают отображаться

Comment: то есть когда код прописанный вот так date_time = "Екатеринбург - " + day + " " + month[month_num] + " " + d.getFullYear() +
" г.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"+ hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

document.getElementById("doc_time").innerHTML = date_time;
setTimeout(clock, 1000);

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
clock();                                       часы просто перестают отобрааться, естественно тег id doctime прописан там где надо и отображается коректно

Comment: если просто удалить if (document.layers) {
document.layers.doc_time.document.write(date_time);
document.layers.doc_time.document.close();
}   - часы перестают вооще показывать и на том месте где должны быть часы - пустота. Помощь плз.